# How to create a change set from build pipeline in Azure DevOps to push some file into my repository

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

I have my code repo on TFS server on azure DevOps. In my CI part of this application, I perform some operation, and after that one file is generated let say it is some kind of log file or report created from its existing version in the repository but now I want to check in back into my code repo from build pipeline.
So what could be the best solution for it?

Comment: Your build process shouldn't be making changes to the repository.

Comment: @Daniel Mann its my requirement as some files produced by build will be bases for the next build. Need to complete my automation flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use TFVC version control, you could invoke REST API [Changesets - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) in a powershell task or TF Command [Checkin command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=azure-devops) in a command line task in your Pipeline to create a new changeset.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=5.0`

```
tf checkin [/author:author name] [/comment:("comment"|@comment file)] 
[/noprompt] [/notes:("Note Name"="note text"|@notefile)] 
[/override:(reason|@reasonfile)] [/recursive] [/saved] [/validate] [itemspec] [/bypass] [/force] [/noautoresolve]  [/login:username,[password]] [/new]
```

If you Git version control, you could invoke REST API [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to push changes to the repository.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=5.0`

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?